# "lxml.etree.XSLTApplyError: Unregistered function" error when doing XSLT transformation

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, xslt, lxml

I have used this simple code to transform XML with XSLT.

```
import lxml.etree as ET

f_xsl = 'transform.xsl'
f_xml = 'input.xml'
f_out = 'output.xml'

transform = ET.XSLT(ET.parse(f_xsl))
result = transform(ET.parse(f_xml))
result.write(f_out)
```

And everything was perfect, it have worked. But now it is not working, code is the same.
I get the error

```
   result = transform(ET.parse(f_xml))
  File "src\lxml\xslt.pxi", line 602, in lxml.etree.XSLT.__call__
lxml.etree.XSLTApplyError: Unregistered function
```

I assume i have upgraded some libraries? I know that lxml supports XPath 1.0, XSLT 1.0 and the EXSLT extensions through libxml2 and libxslt, but how to check versions and how to downgrade within python terminal? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How can we reproduce this? Please see [mcve].

Comment: what does `transform.error_log` tell you? https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#errors-and-messages